# Notation anomaly of symmetric/asymmetric between rev-list and diff

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log, git-rev-list

I am trying to understand the rationale (if there is one) for the difference in notation between `git diff` vs. `git rev-list` or `git log`.

**Clarification:**

I understand what each command does, as I explain below. I am only looking for an explanation as to why Git would use the same notation in two different commands so that one is intuitively (IHO) the opposite of the other.

**git log/rev-list**

In log and rev-list, when you want to see both sides of to diverged branches (symmetrical) the notation is three dots (`...`). E.g.,

```
$ git log --oneline --boundary a...b
* aaaaa Commit to Branch a
| * bbbbb Commit to branch b
|/
o 000000
```

While two dots (`..`) will only show the right side (asymmetrical). E.g.,

```
$ git log --oneline --boundary a..b
* bbbbb Commit to branch b
o 000000
```

**git diff**

However, with git diff two dots (`..`) shows the symmetric diff (my words), i.e., it shows the diff between the two exact commits listed, e.g.,

```
git diff a..b
```

shows the diff between trees of aaaaa and bbbbb.

While three dots (`...`) shows the asymmetric diff, i.e., it shows the the diff between the merge-base of the two commits and the second commit. E.g.,

```
git diff a..b
```

show the diff between the trees of 00000 and bbbbb.

Answer (score 0):

The dot notation in `git-log` specifies a so-called revision range which is exactly what its name says, and what you've described with an example. It is used because the purpose of `git-log` is to display a list (range) of commits.

`git-diff` also uses revision ranges, but if you let me quote now:

> However, "diff" is about comparing two endpoints, not ranges, and the range notations (".." and "...") do not mean a range as defined in the "SPECIFYING RANGES" section in gitrevisions[7].

[From the documentation for git-diff.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Answer (score 0):

**The TL;DR answer:** `git diff` simply doesn't do symmetric difference (nor any sets at all).  It just finds some pair of commits, and diffs that pair.

First (as a sort of aside, for clarity in case various visitors to the answer trip over the word "difference", in "symmetric difference", vs the `git diff` command which is mostly unrelated), let me note here that the *symmetric difference* that `git rev-list` refers to is [the graph-theoretic symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), i.e., the set union minus the set intersection.  In this case the two sets being union-and-intersected are the sets of all commits reachable from either of the two named commits: `git rev-list a...b` parses `a` to get a commit ID, then finds all commits reachable from that commit; it parses and treats `b` similarly; and then the intersection starts at the merge base itself and proceeds back through history.

In your example this leaves just the two branch tip commits.  You added `--boundary` which causes `git rev-list` to include the branch-point commit (where the two histories join at the tip of the set intersection) to get this:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --boundary a...b
* aaaaa Commit to Branch a
| * bbbbb Commit to branch b
|/
o 000000
```

Without `--boundary` we'd omit commit `o` (making the `--oneline --graph` useless).

You are of course also correct that using two dots, `a..b`, you get commits reachable from `b` that are *not* reachable from `a` (normally this also omits the commit identified by `a` itself, but again `--boundary` puts it back into the resulting set).

#### git diff is different

The `git log` and `git rev-list` commands operate on *full sets* of commits.  If you are looking at a set of 75 commits, for instance, `git log` will show you all 75 commits (unless you limit it with `-n`).

The `git diff` command is different.  It produces a comparison (a diff) of *two* commits, and—as long as we ignore "combined diffs", which apply only to merge commits—it will *only* look at two commits.  Given:

```
$ git diff HEAD~5 HEAD
```

it's pretty obvious that this compares commit `HEAD~5` against commit `HEAD`, but even though `HEAD~5..HEAD` names 5 or more<sup>1</sup> commits:

```
$ git diff HEAD~5..HEAD
```

still just compares the same two commits, `HEAD~5` against `HEAD`.

(Note that:

```
$ git diff HEAD..HEAD~5
```

compares the same two commits, but tells you how to modify the `HEAD` commit to produce the `HEAD~5` commit, vs the more typical "how to modify `HEAD~5` to produce `HEAD`".  So the order does matter, but essentially, `git diff` is just replacing the two dots with a space, here.)

The `git diff` command similarly takes over the three-dot notation.  Since it will still only look at two commits, when you give it the three-dot notation, it finds the merge-base commit as usual, but then instead of modifying the input to pretend you simply named the left and right side commits separately, it modifies the input to pretend you named the merge-base on the left, and the right-hand-side commit on the right.

With an actual symmetric difference (set operation), the order of the operands is irrelevant.  But since `git diff` finds a pair and then *replaces the left operand* with the merge-base, and diffs that against the right operand, the order here *does* matter: put the "end result" commit name on the right, because `git diff` will put the merge base in as the left.

---

`HEAD~5..HEAD` produces all commits reachable from `HEAD` that are not reachable from `HEAD~5`.  In a linear structure, that's five commits:

```
... - HEAD~5 - HEAD~4 - HEAD~3 - HEAD~2 - HEAD~1 - HEAD
- excluded -    -------- included: five commits ---------
```

With a branch-and-merge-y structure, though, additional commits are in this set:

```
                       HEAD~3
                      /      \
... - HEAD~5 - HEAD~4         HEAD~2 - HEAD~1 - HEAD
                     \       /
                      HEAD~2^2
```

This structure, for instance, has six commits in the resulting set.